# What triggers the caution message when I am about to ask a new question?

Tags: support, editing, reputation

I only recently got more than 50 reputation points. A recent question was put on hold as too broad. The next time I clicked the Ask button, I was given an automatic warning about asking another question. I don't want to have a drop in rep. Please explain the automatic warning message.

Comment: Consider the advice in this post: [What causes someone to be question banned?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4201)

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is in your question: your last question was put on hold. If you go to ask a new question without first remedying the problem that afflicts your last one, you'll see a warning.

If you *can't* fix your past questions, so be it - the system can be forgiving, to a point. But if *all* your questions are closed, you'll eventually be restricted when you try to ask more. The point at which that happens is > 1 and < 490 closed or downvoted questions.